# Stripping all trailing empty spaces in a column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, strip

I have a **pandas DF** that has many **string elements** that contains words like this:

```
'Frost                              '
```

Which has many leading white spaces in front of it. When I compare this string to:

```
'Frost'
```

I realized that the comparison was **False** due to the leading spaces.

Although I can solve this by iterating over every element of the pandas DF, the process is slow due to the large number of records I have.

This other approach should work, but it is not working:

```
rawlossDF['damage_description'] = rawlossDF['damage_description'].map(lambda x: x.strip(''))
```

So when I inspect an element:

```
rawlossDF.iloc[0]['damage_description']
```

It returns:

```
'Frost                              '
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Replace your function with this:

```
rawlossDF['damage_description'] = rawlossDF['damage_description'].map(lambda x: x.strip())
```

You almost had it right, you needed to get rid off the '' inside strip()

Answer (score 25):

Alternatively you could use [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) method:

```
rawlossDF['damage_description'] = rawlossDF['damage_description'].str.strip()
```

Comment: I tried this on a 5M rows dataset and it takes twice the time compared to map+lambda