# Row comma removal in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
Id          Product                   Age
001         soup,macaroni,             23
002         bread,milk,butter,         18
003         Bread,                     20
```

I want to remove the commas at the end of every Product so that it looks like this:

```
Id          Product                   Age
001         soup,macaroni             23
002         bread,milk,butter         18
003         Bread                     20
```

Comment: `df.Product.str.rstrip(',')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stripping all trailing empty spaces in a column of a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446767/stripping-all-trailing-empty-spaces-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets assume that your dataframe is df.

do the following

```
df["Product"] = df["Product"].apply(lambda x:x.strip(","))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.rstrip(",")`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Product": ["soup,macaroni,", "bread,milk,butter,", "Bread,"]})
df["Product"] = df["Product"].str.rstrip(",")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
             Product
0      soup,macaroni
1  bread,milk,butter
2              Bread
```

Comment: Thank you all so much, i tried all the solutions and they all managed to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can `str.slice` until last value

```
df.Product.str.slice(0, -1)


0        soup,macaroni
1    bread,milk,butter
2                Bread
Name: Product, dtype: object
```